# Copying a folder and it's contents in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to copy a specific folder and it's contents using vb.net, the methods I found all just copy the contents of the specified folder but not the folder as a whole. I want the folder that the path leads to to be copied fully and not only the contents.I have this code at the moment:

```
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test\" & sender.name, "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test2")
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Still only copying the contents of the folder, not the folder itself + contents. Unless I'm using this function wrong somehow.

Answer (score 7):

You can't just copy a directory and all of it's contents with one line of code. You can however "cut and paste" a directory with:

```
Directory.Move("C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test\" & sender.name, "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test2\" & sender.name)
```

To copy you'll need to create a new folder of the same name in the destination directory then copy the contents into it:

```
Dim SourcePath As String = "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test\" & sender.name
Dim DestinationPath As String = "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\test2"
Dim newDirectory As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationPath, Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(SourcePath)))
If Not (Directory.Exists(newDirectory)) Then
     Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirectory)
End If
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(SourcePath, newDirectory)
```

Comment: does this do subdirectories of that directory too?

Comment: Yes, it copies all files and folders.